# Solution Properties in VS 2005

Tags: c++

I have an exe in VS 2005 which has stopped working due to recent changes. The code goes into winmain.cpp in AfxWinMain and then the Window is destroyed

```
if (!pThread->InitInstance())
{
    if (pThread->m_pMainWnd != NULL)
    {
        TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: Destroying non-NULL m_pMainWnd\n");
        pThread->m_pMainWnd->DestroyWindow();  // Comes here
    }
    nReturnCode = pThread->ExitInstance();
    goto InitFailure;
}
```

Help please

Comment: My exe just crashes when I try and run it in debug mode. When I tried to debug it, the debugger goes into VS file winmain.cpp and application is destroyed

Comment: What are Solution Properties and how are they related to the problem?